# How to find greater values from 5 variables and return variable name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 5 variables that are randomly assigned a number from 0 - 500, I was wondering how I could compare all 5 of these variables and then return the greatest value's variable name in console.

The variable names are: count1, count2, count3, count4, count5

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var x = [
    { val: count1, variableName: "count1" },
    { val: count2, variableName: "count2" },
    { val: count3, variableName: "count3" },
    { val: count4, variableName: "count4" },
    { val: count5, variableName: "count5" }];
```

Sort the array x in ascending order on the attribute val.

x[4].variableName is the name of the largest value holder.

Comment: this returns only the greatest value. Not the name of the variable having the greatest value.

Comment: Oh, you need the name of the variable. I misread, let me modify the code.

Comment: you will have to then maintain the mapping between the value and variable name to achieve this

Comment: yes, i just modified the code above. Sorting is very simple so i've not added code of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps**

1. create an array of objects. Where each object is a mapping between the variable name and its value
2. sort the array in ascending order based on the value property
3. take the 4th element's variableName property

**Below is the code snippet**

```
// assuming these are the random numbers from 0 - 500
let count1=10, count2=30, count3=15, count4=7, count5=23;

// create an array of objects. Where each object is a mapping between the variable name and its value
let tmpArray=[
  {
    value: count1,
    variableName: 'count1'
  },
  {
    value: count2,
    variableName: 'count2'
  },
  {
    value: count3,
    variableName: 'count3'
  },
  {
    value: count4,
    variableName: 'count4'
  },
  {
    value: count5,
    variableName: 'count5'
  }
]

// sort the array in ascending order based on the value property and then take the 4th element's variableName property
let highesVariableName=tmpArray.sort((a,b)=>a.value-b.value)[4].variableName;

console.log(highesVariableName); // count2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var countobj = { count1: 230, count2: 123 , count3: 428, count4: 67, count5: 198 };

var arrVals = Object.keys( countobj ).map(function ( key ) { return countobj[key]; });
var minVal = Math.min.apply( null, arrVals );
var maxVal = Math.max.apply( null, arrVals );

var minVar =  Object.keys(countobj).filter(function(key) {return countobj[key] === minVal})[0];
var maxVar =  Object.keys(countobj).filter(function(key) {return countobj[key] === maxVal})[0];

document.write( 'Minimum val is ' + minVal + ' from variable '+ minVar +', Maximum val is ' + maxVal + ' from variable ' + maxVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find max value by creating object:-

```
var count1 = 100, count2 = 200, count3 = 300, count4 = 400, count5 = 500;


var tempObj = {
 "count1" : count1,
 "count2" : count2,
 "count3" : count3,
 "count4" : count4,
 "count5" : count5
}

var max  = Object.entries(tempObj).reduce((prev, current) => (prev[1] > current[1]) ? prev : current)[0];
```